# What are the advantages and disadvantages of changing the browser window icon?

Tags: website-design

I have been experimenting with ways to notify a user when a running web application requires their attention.

[image: badges]

[Adding badges to the favorite icon seems to work well](http://davealger.com/apps/favicon/) but I am having a hard time backing that up with data.

**Is there any reason that changing the window icon *at all* is bad UX?**

If not then I'll go ahead and test it out with users otherwise I will explore other alternatives.  (other suggestions are welcome thanks)

Comment: A badge likely won't draw too much attention. Blinking or changing color is likely the way to go. As the objective is to draw attention--assuming this is a benefit to the user, then it makes sense.

Comment: When you get a new message on Facebook, it cycles between the regular title and a title indicating someone messaged you, creating what I've seen described as a "flashing" effect which would grab the user's attention more quickly than a badge on the favicon, especially if the favicon is visually busy to begin with

Comment: Good point rach.  I'll test changing the title and see if people notice that more

Comment: (Note that the latests versions Safari (and maybe other browsers?) aren't displaying this icon in the URL bar.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question. No, there's no good reason that it's a problem. Take a look at how Invision does it; they do it with the text instead of the icon.

DA01 is right, it shouldn't be too distracting. What banking sites do is have a pop-up when you've got a minute left before you're logged out, which works very well. Google Calendar does something similar for an upcoming event. Depending on the use of your website/webapp, that may be the better route.